# list out of range error when using soup.select('placeholder')[0].get_text() in Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to scraping and I'm trying to use Beautiful soup to get the Wheelbase value ( eventually other things) from a wikipedia page ( I'll deal with robots.txt later) [This is the guide I've been using](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python)

Two questions
1.) How do I resolve the error below?
2.) How do I scrape the value in the cell that contains wheelbase is it just "td#Wheelbase td" ?

The error I get is

```
File "evscraper.py", line 25, in <module>
wheelbase_data['Wheelbase'] = soup.select('div#Wheelbase h3')       [0].get_text()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks for any help!

```
__author__ = 'KirkLazarus'
import re
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


response =requests.get ('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Model_S')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)



wheelbase_data['Wheelbase'] = soup.select('div#Wheelbase h3')[0].get_text()

print wheelbase_data
```

Comment: Presumably, `soup.select('div#Wheelbase h3')` is returning an empty list, so trying to access its first element causes an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your first problem is with your selector. There's no div with the ID of "Wheelbase" on that page, so it's returning an empty list.

What follows is by no means perfect, but will get you what you want, only because you know the structure of the page already:

```
import re
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

wheelbase_data = {}

response =requests.get ('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Model_S')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.get('href') == "/wiki/Wheelbase":
        wheelbase = link
        break

wheelbase_data['Wheelbase'] = wheelbase.parent.parent.td.text
```

Comment: I get what's going on here but I'm getting a wheelbase_data is not defined error.

Comment: That's probably because there's no dictionary called wheelbase_data. Before you assign a value to `response`, put a line in that says `wheelbase_data = {}` to declare and empty dict. I'll update my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for the incorrect path.  I've had to do something similar in the past.. I'm not sure if this is the best approach but certainly worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


car_data = pd.DataFrame()

models = ['Tesla_Model_S','Tesla_Model_X']

for model in models:

    wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{0}".format(model)
    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
    req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "infobox hproduct" })

    for row in table.findAll("tr")[2:]:
        try:
            field = row.findAll("th")[0].text.strip()
            val = row.findAll("td")[0].text.strip()
            car_data.set_value(model,field,val)
        except:
            pass

car_data
```